# Wordpress media buttons don't work without item attached to?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, media

I'm currently developing theme settings for my Wordpress theme, i need media buttons in order the user can attach files for the homepage. This files are totally independent.
This medias buttons dont work except when i display a Wordpress editor, can anyone have a solution cleaner than hide the editor with a css hack ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I did it like this:

in the form

```
<label for="upload_image" class="upload">
    <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="<?php echo get_option('ad_image'); ?>" /> 
    <input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Choose Image" />
```

and then to display the current image selected.

```
<p><strong>Current Image:</strong>
    <?php if (get_option('ad_image')){ echo '<br /><img src="'.get_option('ad_image').'" height="150" width="220"';} else{echo 'None Selected';}?>
    </p>
```

and then enqueue this javascript in the options page

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var _custom_media = true,
      _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;

  $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {
    var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
    var button = $(this);
    var id = button.attr('id').replace('_button', '');
    _custom_media = true;
    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
      if ( _custom_media ) {
        $("#"+id).val(attachment.url);
      } else {
        return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
      };
    }

    wp.media.editor.open(button);
    return false;
  });

  $('.add_media').on('click', function(){
    _custom_media = false;
  });
});
```